# Model objects for DAO pattern and service layer

Tags: java, oop, dao, many-to-one, service-layer

Say I have the following tables in a database with a one to many relationship:

`Television`

Columns: id(PK), description, model, brand_id(FK), type_id(FK)

`Type`

Columns: id(PK), name

To represent a Television I can create the following model object:

```
public class Television {
    String description;
    String model;
    String brand;
    TelevisionType type;

    Television(String description, String model, String brand, TelevisionType type) {
        this.description = description;
        this.model = model;
        this.brand = brand;
        this.type = type;
    }
}

public enum TelevisionType {
    QLED,
    OLED,
    LCD
}
```

A basic version of my DAO interfaces could look like this:

```
public interface TelevisionDao {
    List<Television> getAllTelevisions();
}

public interface TelevisionTypeDao {
    TelevisionType getTelevisionType(int id);
}
```

But in my service layer, how can I supply getTelevisionType with an ID? I don't want to store an ID in my Television model object. Shouldn't the model be entirely blind to the storage layer of my application? I'm not even sure how I would return my `Television` object using `getAllTelevisions` as populating its `type` field would require a call to my `TelevisionTypeDao` from within the `TelevisionDao`, which would defeat the point of having a service layer.

Can someone please clear up how this sort of situation is managed when using this pattern? Thank you.

Comment: I would have an Integer id field in the object that is nullable.  When you save the model object, have the DAO get the generated key and update the id.

Comment: Thanks @duffymo but I'm not quite sure what you mean. I have no use for the id in any other part of my application, except for in my service layer, which only needs it to retrieve the rows category. Also, storing an id in my `Television` model would mean it would contain both an Integer id field and the TelevisionType type field, which doesn't seem like the right way to go about it.

Comment: There is a scenario where you will need the primary key id outside the service layer: If your UI presents all the Televisions in a table and allows a user to select one to update or delete, you'll need to POST the ID of the selected instance to tell the service side which one to change.